# Solve $\frac{5}{x+3}+\frac{2}{2x+6}=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I want to solve $\frac{5}{x+3}+\frac{2}{2x+6}=4$ for $x$

I try this;

$5(2x+6)+2(x+3)=4(x+3)(2x+6)$

$12x+36 = 4(2x^2+12x+18)$

$8x^2+36x+36=0$
Where I would then go to the formula, however the answer says -1.5, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: What happens when you use the quadratic formula to solve $8x^2+36x+36=0$? (You haven't done anything wrong yet.)

Comment: I get -1.5 and -3, however the website I am looking it gives only an answer of -1.5.

Comment: something goes wrong when x is -3 - look at the first part of the equations

Comment: You have the equation $2x^2+9x+9 = 0$. If you multiply that with $x$ to get $2x^3+9x^2+9x = 0$. This clearly has another solution: $x = 0$, which isn't what your original solutions are either. Basically, things can go wrong if you multiply with terms like $(x+3)$, because then all of a sudden $x = -3$ is the equivalent of multiplying both sides with $0$.

Answer (score 1):

***You could solve it this way:***

The second fraction, $\frac {2}{2x+6}$ can be simplified into $\frac 1{x+3}$. Thus,
$$\frac 5{x+3}+\frac 2{2x+6}=4\implies\frac 6{x+3}=4\tag1$$
And cross multiplying, we get $4(x+3)=6\implies x=x=-\frac 32$

---

*As to where you went wrong*, nothing has gone wrong yet. Use the quadratic formula and see what you get!

> **Hint:** You *will* get two solutions. One of them doesn't work (i.e it's extraneous).

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by extranous. I have no idea why the solution has 2 answers however only 1 is correct! This is impossible!!

Comment: @MathsWiz Extraneous basically means one of them is wrong. When you plug in the second answer, (I'll spare you the math and say the answer is $x=-3$), the denominators of the LHS become equal to zero. And since you can never divide by $0$, the answer won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic equation you have obtained has two solutions: $-3$ and $-\frac{3}{2}$. The latter one is the correct answer. The former one is incorrect because it would lead to division by $0$ when we plug it into the original equation.

However, the problem need not be solved via quadratic equation. Observe that
$\frac{5}{x + 3} + \color{red}{\frac{2}{2x + 6}} = \frac{5}{x + 3} + \color{red}{\frac{1}{x + 3}} = \frac{6}{x + 3}$. Then the equation could be written as $4(x + 3) = 6$, so $x = \frac{6}{4} - 3 = -\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by extranous. I have no idea why the solution has 2 answers however only 1 is correct! This is impossible!!

Answer (score 1):

The solutions of $8x^2+36x+36=0$ are $-1.5$ and $-3$, but the latter is not a solution of the original equation. This new, false solution comes when you multiply the equation by $(x+3)(2x+6)$, which **is not the lcm** of the denominators.

Note that $2x+6=2(x+3)$.

**An example to show what's happening**:

Take the equation
$$3x+5=-1$$
The solution is $x=-2$. If you multiply both sides of any equation by a **non zero** number, you get another equation, whose solutions are the same. But if you multiply both sides by $0$ you get $0=0$.

Now, if you multiply both sides by, say, $x+4$, we don't know if $x+4$ is zero or not. So we obtain another equation with two solutions:
$$3x^2+17x+20=-x-4$$
$$3x^3+18x+24=0$$
$$x=\left\lbrace\begin{align}&-2\\&-4\end{align}\right.$$

One of the solutions is the original one. The other is the value for which the factor $x+4$, that we multiplied by, vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce your quadratic equation it will become $2x^2+9x+9=0$. Now apply quadratic formula to find the x.

$x=\frac{-9\pm\sqrt{9^2-4*2*9}}{4} $. Solve this one and find x. You will get two answers which are -3  and -1.5

Second one is correct but the first one is not because on the LHS of your question you have 5/x+3 as one of term. If you apply x=-3 here you will be dividing 5 by 0 which is not possible, same in the case of other term(2/2x+6) . I let you conclude now.

Comment: Thank you, however I get 2 solutions, when the book gives just 1?

Comment: I have edited the question. Look at it now

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{5}{x+3}$+$\frac{2}{2(x+3)}$=4

$\frac{(5*2+2)}{2(x+3)}$=4

12=8(x+3)

x=$\frac{-12}{8}$

x=$\frac{-3}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Three answers:

i) $\frac n0$ is undefined.  If you are ever given an expression $\frac 5{x+3}$ you know from the very beginning that it is impossible for these to be $\frac 50$ so it is impossible for $x +3 =0$.  $x +3 \ne 0$ and $x \ne -3$.

So whatever you do, you know $x = -3$ will not be an acceptable solution.

So to get rid of the fractions you went from

$A: \frac 5{x+3} + \frac 2{2x +6} = 4$ to

$B:  5(2x+6) + 2(x+3) = 4(x+6)(x+3)$

These two equations are *not* the same.  If $A$ is true then $B$ is true and you can get $B$ *from* $A$ but if $B$ is true you don't know that $A$ is true. All the solutions to $A$ are solutions to $B$, but $B$ has (maybe) *more* solutions than $A$ does. In $A$ it is impossible for $x + 3 = 0$ and for $2x + 6 = 0$.  But in $B$ it is not.

This is could an "extraneous solution".  You did this the correct way to solve but you need to note that when you multiply by an "unknown" to get rid of a denominator, you must check whether the "unknown" adds some "extraneous" solutions.

So you solve $B$ and get $x = -1.5$ or $x =-3$.  But you already know that $x=-3$ is not an acceptable answer.  It is an acceptable answer to $B$ but not to $A$.  So the answer in $x = -1.5$.

ii) When you have $\frac ab + \frac cd = e$ so $ad +cb = ebd$ notice you only need to multiply by the greatest common multiple of $b$ and $d$.  You don't have to multiply by *all* of $b$ and $b$.

To get rid of the denominator in

$\frac 5{x+3} + \frac 2{2x+6} = 4$

we don't have to multiply by $(x+3)(2x+6)$.  $2x + 6 = 2(x+3)$ so we only have to multiply by $2x+6$.

$\frac 5{x+3} + \frac 2{2x+6} = 4$

$5*2 + 2 = 4(2x + 3)$.

Indeed we could have only multiplied by $x+3$ to get $5 + \frac 22 = 4(x+3)$.

iii) You could have reduced $\frac 2{2x+6} = \frac 1{x+3}$ from the start.

$\frac 5{x+3} + \frac 2{2x + 6} = 4$

$\frac 5{x+3} + \frac 1{x+3} = 4$

$\frac 6{x+3} =4 $

$6 = 4(x+3)$.

====

Note ii) and iii) show that this is not actually a quadratic problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have $5\over{x+3}$ + $2\over{2x+6}$ = 4.

This can be rewritten as $10\over{2x+6}$ + $2\over{2x+6}$ = 4.

Multiplying by 2x + 6 on each side, we get: 10 + 2 = 4(2x + 6)

Dividing by 4 on each side: 3 = 2x + 6

$\Rightarrow$ -3 = 2x $\Rightarrow$ x = $-3\over{2}$